# How to use psexec in Windows XP

Tags: pstools

I read some related document on above query:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html

I used this command on in my comman d prompt :

```
psexec \\PCname -u UserName -p ****** "C:\Program Files\Messenger\msmsgs.exe"
```

But i can't see Messenger on either my or on remote machine.

I am trying to do [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/206658/how-can-i-use-one-exe-on-multiple-machines)

Answer (score 1):

Ways to do what you want (on an all-Windows domain):

- Make your application run without being installed. Put it on a network share. Trust the network share, so programs will launch without security warnings. Make a shortcut to it.
- Make your application deploy as an MSI installer, deploy it by group policy. Update it, redeploy it, and have people reboot to pick up the new one.
- install a server with Remote Desktop Services (and appropriate licenses), and install your program on it, and then publish it as a Remote App (it runs on the server, you see the window on your client).
- Use a deployment tool such as ClickOnce
- Use another app deployment solution to push it out to the desktops, maybe Microsoft App-V, more likely a third party. Altiris SVS used to be in this space, I don't know what's current at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but you can try to add a -i parameter, so that the process you're trying to launch will run in an interactive mode in the specified target computer.

Edit : I just saw what you're trying to acheive, and I don't think you can acheive that with psexec, which is used to execute process on remote computers.
Here, you may what to try an application presentation solution, like Xenapp or Windows 2008 remote desktop services

Comment: You certainly can do remote execution with `PSExec`, but only for non-interactive processes (nothing will be shown on the remote computers screen).

Comment: how can do this via "Xenapp " or with any other solution ?